# Asking for a different position (before accepting an offer)

Tags: communication, position

I am a senior at a university, and I will be graduating in the spring (May 2018).

Last summer, I interned at a company in a Data Science position. They offered me a return offer, but it was for a Full Stack position. If I am more interested in returning in a data science position, how do I communicate this to the company?

The courses that I am taking and my career interests are currently focused on Data Science.

Answer (score 2):

> If I am more interested in returning in a data science position, how
>   do I communicate this to the company?

Just tell them what you are looking for and if they might have any positions open. Ask if you can use your supervisor from last summer as a reference.

Alternatively, look on their website in the "Careers" section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you worked with a recruiter (typically a "Campus Recruiter") for both your internship and your full-time offer. He/she might be a good place to start since they are aware of what you've done previously at your company. Just reach out to him/her and tell him/her your thoughts.

Alternatively, if you had a good internship and a good relationship with your boss during your internship, feel free to reach out to him/her and let them know that you got an offer as a Full Stack Developer, but you'd really like to join his/her team as a Data Scientist.

As @Joe pointed out, you could look at the "Careers" section, but from my experience, positions made specifically for college recruiting often times don't appear to the public and you have to go through your campus recruiter directly.